# Store values and access them by name with delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I need to store values(float) and "pair" them with a string. then I need to find the highest float value and return it with its paired string.

I've found no way to do this since 2d arrays must be of the same type(as far as I know) and I haven't found anything to do so. Any help much appreciated.

Here's a small example:

```
type
TPerson = record
name: string;
money: double;

DataSet
'Me' , 100
'you', 200
'bill', 250
'mark', 500
```

I'm trying to write a function like:

```
function whosRich(DataSet): TPerson;
```

Comment: Take a look on Array of record, Objectlist, dictionary ....

Comment: Generics `TList<TPerson>` collection (e.g. even sorted by the `Money` field if you'll need to get e.g. the smallest value, or the value in the middle later on) could be also fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just create an array of TPerson instead of a 2D one? The simplest way to find the highest value is then to walk through the array and check the records one by one.

Comment: Its late here and now I feel dumb. I should ve figured it out but thanks anyways!